# Is it customary to not have any addresses in an organization available for private networks?

Tags: ip-address

I encountered this setup in the wild: a campus has a big internal network.

They're using IPv4s from `10.0.0.0/8`, `172.16.0.0/12` and `192.168.0.0/16` as expected.
The part that surprised me is that they have not identified a block to never assign to any machine.

For me it means that I need to come up with a solution for my containerized services that currently have the same IP as an existing host. Ideally I'd use an unassigned block (that is planned to never be assigned in the future) but they only have a concept of assigned blocks. The only solution I was given is to list how many IPs I need, and they'll assign them to me.

My question is: what are the advantages of this policy? Is it customary? I fail to understand it, but I'm a developer and not a network engineer, hence my request for feedback here.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about networks you do not directly control are off-topic here. You need to work this out with the network administrators.

Answer (score 3):

> what are the advantages of this policy?

Accountability. They know every address within their network, and where it should be. Should any "foreign" addresses be seen, it's something to investigate. While they could also pre-allocate blocks for "internal", never-to-be-on-the-LAN use, they will *inevitably* find their way out of whatever island they're supposed to be in. (even more so when non-network types are using them.)

> Is it customary?

This is treading on "opinion", but experience says "*yes and no.*" There's no rule, or "best practice" on this. You may find organizations that explicitly assign all blocks (as yours does.) Others set aside private internal blocks for such insular uses. And others don't do either. In my experience, the latter is most common. Outside ISP or hosting infrastructure, address management is surprisingly lax. And, yes, the "pick something no one is using" method is a recipe for disaster -- what isn't "in use" today, may be tomorrow, and how exactly does one know a block isn't in use?

Answer (score 2):

If your subnet interacts in *any* way with the company network - even when there is no direct routing - you need to use an explicitly allocated subnet address. Failing that, local routing can become ambiguous or some parts of your network become inaccessible.

A *never-used-anywhere* range (which is explicitly allocated as well, by the way) could potentially work (provided you never need to interact with another island using the same range). But if there isn't such a range, simply use an allocated network from your management. Managing *all* addresses in a company in a strict way is a good idea imho.